# Scroll current tab highlight in ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, viewpagerindicator

At the moment, if I'm using TabPageIndicator in Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator the current tab is only highlighted when the ViewPager snaps to a single fragment. What I was hoping for is the underline to slide over as I slowly swipe the ViewPager then snap into place when my swipe is complete.

Can I accomplish this using ViewPagerIndicator? If so, how? If not, is there a different library that might be better suited?

I have to support down to 2.3 - 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

When you install the ViewPagerIndicator demo from the PlayStore (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viewpagerindicator.sample) you can see what is possible. Currently I don't think this is possible. The line only changes when you actually switched tabs.

But still, in my opinion it is still the best library when you want to work with tabs.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I've looked through the library and found where the highlighting is occurring and it certainly doesn't lend itself to what I'm attempting. I was hoping someone had done something similar to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with this library:

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip